# What tense are "I will have been given the money by then" and "I will be given the money tomorrow"?

Tags: future-tense, future-perfect

> "I will have been given the money by then"
>   "I will be given the money tomorrow"

I'm studying tenses/aspects right now and I realize I could just use similar sentences in future perfect such as *"I will have received the money by then"*, or in future progressive such as *"I will be receiving the money tomorrow"*.

However, I was wondering if constructions similar to *will have been given [something]* and *"will be given [something]"* are correct and what tense would that even be.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference between the construction in:

1a *"I will have received the money by then."*
1b *"I will be receiving the money tomorrow."*

and the one in:

2a *"I will have been given the money by then."*
2b *"I will be given the money tomorrow."*

is not one of **tense** or **aspect**, but rather of ***voice***. The latter pair of sentences use a construction in the passive voice.

Answer (score 0):

"I will have been given the money by then" is Future Perfect tense in the Passive Voice.

"I will be given the money tomorrow" is Simple Future tense in the Passive Voice.