# what is the tense of "will been given"?

Tags: tense

What is the tense of "will been given" in the following sentence:

This summer, Professor John Lienhard **will been given** the Donald Q. Kern Award by the American Institute of Chemical Engineers in recognition of expertise in a given field of heat transfer, transport phenomena, and energy processes.

source: MIT MechE's social media

Comment: A quick search on the internet can easily solve your problem.

Comment: Are you asking about the **tense**? Or the **aspect**? Or even the **voice**? [**They are different**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/316690/150280)

Comment: What's more, this is a [duplicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143306/what-tense-are-i-will-have-been-given-the-money-by-then-and-i-will-be-given-t)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What tense are "I will have been given the money by then" and "I will be given the money tomorrow"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143306/what-tense-are-i-will-have-been-given-the-money-by-then-and-i-will-be-given-t)

Comment: _Will been given_ is not any tense - either you have missed out _have_, or the original is a typo.

Comment: thanks all, I think this is not a duplicate. The one that you mentioned is the future perfect tense (will+**have**+been+pp) and I don't have any problem with the tense, but in the above sentence, I don't understand why the "**have**" word has been dropped? so it might be a typo

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a quick google search can provide the answer to this

Answer (score 1):

This is just a typo. The text should read, "will be given ..."

Comment: Can you clarify why you believe that? The system has flagged this as low quality because of its length.

Comment: It looks like the sentence is an active sentence and has a subject. Why did they write it in passive form?

Comment: @mdewey I believe that because the sentence, as written, is not grammatical English.

Comment: @mdewey The modal verb “will” should be followed by an infinitive, but it is instead followed by two past participles. Hence, it is not grammatical.

Comment: It's a typo. They happen. By native speakers and non-native. English spelling is so stupid it makes English learners feel stupid. But it's English spelling.